# How can use div when using django block

Tags: python, css, django

I'm using Django 3.1.7 in the backend and have a three-page
1.index(the home page)
2.Transhow
I used block to reduce and reuse index code.
I have a few pages and all pages need to use the same CSS but when I use block statement the div doesn't
work.

```
   <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="brand">
                <h1><a href="#">حسابداری</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="searchbox">
                <form action="search" method="get">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="حساب مورد نظر" class="text">
                    <input type="submit" value="جستجو" class="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
             <div class="clear">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div id="toolbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000" class="active">خانه</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Account_show">مدیریت حساب</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Trans_show">مدیریت اسناد</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Article_show">دفتر روزنامه</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Category_show">گروه سرفصل</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about_us">درباره ما</a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout_page">خروج</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            {% block main %}

            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

Tran page

```
{%block main%}
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ردیف</th>
            <th>شماره سند</th>
            <th>تاریخ</th>
            <th>توضیحات</th>
            <th>عطف</th>
            <th>ویرایش</th>
        </tr>
        {%for record in records%}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="article/{{record.id}}">{{record.id}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="article/{{record.id}}">{{record.sanadno}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="article/{{record.id}}">{{record.tdate}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="article/{{record.id}}">{{record.tdesc}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="article/{{record.id}}">{{record.tres}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="edit/Tran_edit/{{record.id}}">ویرایش</a></td>
            </tr>
        {%endfor%}
        {% if records.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">اولین</a>
            <a href="?page={{ records.previous_page_number }}">قبل</a>
        {% endif %}
      صفحه {{ records.number }} از {{ records.paginator.num_pages }}. {% if records.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ records.next_page_number }}">بعدی</a>
    <a href="?page={{ records.paginator.num_pages }}">قبلی</a>
{% endif %}

    </table>
{%endblock%}
```

css page

```
#content {
    width: 1050px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#brand {
    float: right;
}

h1 a{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight:100;
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#searchbox{
    float: left;
    background: linear-gradient(#E1F1B2,#BCEA5E);
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

.text{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #E36A23;
    background: white url(images/search.png) left center no-repeat;
}

.submit{
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background: #A751D6;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#toolbar{
    height: 70px;
    background: linear-gradient(#F2F084,#D8D83B);
    padding: 7px 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    
}

#toolbar ul li{
    float: right;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #5d12e7;
}

#toolbar ul li:last-child{
    border-left: none;
    
}


#toolbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #5d12e7;
    line-height: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: font-size 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: font-size 0.5s ease;
    transition: font-size 0.5s ease;
}

#toolbar ul li a:hover , #toolbar ul li a.active{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #B314DB;
}

#main{
    background: linear-gradient(#E3F2B6,#B8EA55);
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
```

the main div is not working properly.
when I run my server the main div goes to the left.
This happens on all HTML pages that use blocks.
The rest of the divs work properly, but the ones that use blocks do not work properly.

Comment: Where is your page styles declared?

Comment: Did you extend your page correctly?